# Javascript how to build loop with unconstant time of iterations

Tags: javascript, facebook, loops, vk

need to be consulted by JS jedi.
Situation: I got array with USER_IDs and need to call social network function to post on their walls. So I need to launch wallpost function, listen to its answer and then continue iterating my loop. 
Code I have written is able to leave post to the last person from array, to the first, to none and many others useful functions :s . Need your help jedis

```
    function showPost() {
            for(i in selFriends) {  //selFriends - massive with user_id 
                    alert(i+' '+selFriends[i]); //checkplace
                    VK.api('wall.post',{
                            owner_id:selFriends[i], //element
                            message:htmlres,  // content 
                            attachment:photoID // id of the mediacontent
                    },function(receive) {
                            showPost();
                    });
            return;
            }
    }
```

This code need to be fixed, because now it is just iterationg wall.post for 1st element from the massive.
By the way method VK.api is almost similar to Facebook UI method 'feed'.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: if anyone can understand what the hell this question is asking, I will be very impressed

Comment: That "massive" thing is an array, right?

Comment: The force is not very strong on this.

Comment: That return statement looks highly suspect, young padawan.

Comment: i'm lold :D massive = array ofc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no jedi, but are you trying to run the first index in your `selFriends` array through `VK.api`, and call the *next* index in the callback?  And then repeat for each element in the selFriends array?

```
function postId(index) {
   if (index === selFriends.length) 
       return;
   VK.api('wall.post',{
       owner_id:selFriends[i], //element
       message:htmlres,  // content 
       attachment:photoID // id of the mediacontent
       },function(receive) {
           postId(index + 1);
   });
}
```

And then

```
function showPost() {
    postId(0);     
}
```

Comment: it's OK at the moment. Sorry for wasting time, got sleepless night :s

Comment: *The force is strong within this one.*